# Unable to select the wordrpess posts publish button by JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to disable the publish button and enable it only on when condition is met, but I can't seem to select the button by jQuery, my code does not work even though everything is fine, but when I try to directly write the code on console it does work just fine. also this problem happens only on Gutenberg editor not the classic editor.

I have tried to clear browsers cache but nothing seems to work. tried to select other element on the Gutenberg editor but no luck.

```
$('.editor-post-publish-panel__toggle').first().attr("disabled", true);
```

Comment: If when you run the code on the console and it does the job, it means that there is nothing wrong with the selector. Please check that when the code is executed, the DOM is the same as when you run it in the console. I suspect that the DOM is different when your code is executed.

Comment: nope, everything looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we have **Gutenberg** as an editor it has it's won ruleset.
You need to enqueue your javascript to Gutenberg editor

```
function myguten_enqueue() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'myguten-script',
        plugins_url( 'myguten.js', __FILE__ )
    );
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'myguten_enqueue' );
```

[Click here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/javascript/loading-javascript/) for reference